# How can I find posts that have been answered by two users?

Tags: feature-request, search, users

**Q1:** How can I find posts that have been answered by two users? For example user:1000 and user:1500? Or more generally a set of posts where two users have intersected, consisting of comments, questions, and answers.

**Q2:** Is it possible to see my questions on the profile page of a user who answered my posts? Something like <kbd>My Posts</kbd>, similar to the

<kbd>All</kbd>
<kbd>Questions</kbd>
<kbd>Answers</kbd>
<kbd>Votes</kbd>
<kbd>Newest</kbd>

tabs in the user profile.

Comment: This consists of two distinct questions, only one of which is a feature request.  Please limit yourself to one question per post.

Comment: Re: *Or more generally a set of posts where two users have intersected, consisting of comments, questions, answers.* You might check this post on MathOverflow Meta: [Is it possible to search for posts/questions of an user $X$ commented on/answered by the user $Y$?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3266) In particular, the query called "Have we met?" might be of interest. Do not forget to switch sites from MathOverflow to Math when executing those queries.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: the first two link in answer you linked to is not return results properly. For example the user 26501 and me have met each other in many MSE posts but that query returns nothing!!

Comment: @C.F.G Could you provide the link which is not working? Did you switch the sites from MO to MSE? When I tried the query [Comments left by a user on your posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/113150/comments-left-by-a-user-on-your-posts?userid=272127&commenterid=26501) (with parameters 272127 and 26501), I got 12 comments. I got 12 result also from [Have we met?](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/25355/have-we-met?MyId=272127&TheirId=26501).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Aha, I confused by site icon. If it is in MSE it shows Meta icon and vice versa?

Comment: When you choose math.SE, you can see the *main* site icon in two places near the top. (Look at the text "Compose query" and below it.) The switch sites dialogue shows the meta icon - through which you can quickly switch to meta. (You can see this icon also in Glorfindel's answer.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for these kind of things.

For Q1, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1271289/questions-answered-by-two-specific-users?UserId1=12042&UserId2=6312) lists the questions answered by the two highest reputation users on the site, but you can easily adjust the user IDs.

[image]

Q2 requires a [slightly different query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1271290/questions-asked-by-user-x-answered-by-user-y?AnswerOwnerUserId=629362&UserId=272127) (I took your user ID and a random person who answered one of your latest questions).

Please note that SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning. Feel free to fork my queries for your own experiments. If you're new to SQL, you can have a look at the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial), and there's a [chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) dedicated to it.